# Redirect with RedirectToRouteResult does not work from other area

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have this ActionFilter

```
public class AppOfflineFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName != "AppOffLine" &&
            filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UserHostName != "127.0.0.1")
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                 new RouteValueDictionary(
                     new  { action = "AppOffLine", Controller = "Home" }));
        }
    }
}
```

It works from the start page which is does not reside under a Area, it does not work from an area because it will redirect to /Area/Home/Appoffline instead of /Home/AppOffline

Can it be fixed?

Also is there a way of speciefing which controller / action to redirect to using Generics and strongly typed code?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Try assigning the `area` route token to an empty string:

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { 
    action = "AppOffLine", 
    controller = "Home", 
    area = "" 
}));
```

Comment: thanks, it save my lot of time, while I was digging around the way to do so :)

Comment: Bam! Thanks! I was stuck on this one for a minute

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 13):

you must specify area like this:

```
public class AppOfflineFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName != "AppOffLine" &&
            filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UserHostName != "127.0.0.1")
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary(
                    new { action = "AppOffLine", Controller = "Home",
                          area = "YourAreaName" })); //<<<<THIS
        }
    }
}
```

and if you want to redirect to a non-area zone (like `/Home/Index`), set '`area`' to an empty string; like:

```
area=""
```