# How to apply Global ActionFilter to all controllers and return Result?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, global-filter

How to properly apply global action filter so it triggers on all actions, and then returns Custom result of action that triggered the filter? I will provid example of what i have done so far, but **been unable to trigger** the `filterContext.Result = ...`

*Global.asax*

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    filters.Add(new RequestCounter());
}

public class RequestCounter : ActionFilterAttribute
{

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {  
          if (!LogCounter())
          {
               if (!filterContext.IsChildAction)
               {
                   var values = new RouteValueDictionary(new
                   {
                       controller = "Account",
                       action = "LogOff"
                   });

                   filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(values);

                   //--> Here, the action is not redirected to LogOff method,
                   //    the goal is to logoff user, program just continues???
               }
          }

          base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
     }
}
```

How to properly redirect to LogOff() method, from this context, using Result or some other way as well?? thanks!

Comment: Just taking a wild shot in the dark. But would you want to process this using [OnActionExecuted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute.onactionexecuted) instead? (my thinking being that your action may override anything you do once it has completed)

Comment: @musefan, this is an option to, i have tried this, but does not  affect final result, thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @SergRogovtsev, I am tying to accomplish triggering Account/Logoff when LogCounter() returns false, I am using RedirectToRouteResult, which is not working!

Comment: That's your solution instead of your problem (refer to MacConnell for this distinction). If what you need is to allow user access only if `LogCounter` us `true`, why don't you use `AuthorizationAttribute`?

Comment: @SergRogovtsev, this is true, and it works, but why is `Result` prop on `ActionFilterAttribute` not doing the job right, here is [statement](http://develoq.net/2011/action-filters/) for this.

Comment: @Ingol it obviously doesn't work or you wouldn't be here. That why I imply that you may have chosen wrong solution for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900333/redirect-with-redirecttorouteresult-does-not-work-from-other-area#6900386) on a similar question, you need to assign the `Area` parameter to an empty string e.g.

```
var values = new RouteValueDictionary(new
{
    controller = "Account",
    action = "LogOff",
    area = ""
});
```